# Not a supported wheel on this platform for Pymssql

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, pymssql, python-wheel

I am trying to install Pymssql. However if I try to install it with command line `python -m pip install pymssql` then the current error occurs `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 76: invalid start byte` so I decided to install it with the wheel file. I am on a 64bits architecure and I am currently using Python 3.7.3 on 64bits but when I download the file and place it in my 'Python37' folder then execute the line `python -m pip install pymssql-2.1.4-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl` I have the error message : `pymssql-2.1.4-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.` 
Can someone help me I am really stoped in my work because of this.

Thank you by advance.

Comment: Perhaps you have 32-bit Python and you're trying to install 64-bit wheel. `python --version && python -c "import struct; print(struct.calcsize('P') * 8)"`to check Python version and 32/64-bitness.

Comment: I already tried this method and I am running Python 64bits. But thanks for the help